# Conversion from const aiScene* to aiScene*, ASSIMP

Tags: c++, assimp

i'm trying to apply [FindSceneCenter](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/ProcessHelper.cpp) function from ASSIMP lib to [aiScene*](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_scene.html) object, which was imported from file.

```
    // Read file via ASSIMP
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
    // Check for errors
    if(!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) // if is Not Zero
    {
        cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
        return;
    }
    aiVector3D out, min, max;
    Assimp::FindSceneCenter(scene, out, min, max); // Problem here
```

Problem is that this function require [aiScene*] object as parameter, but imported scene is [const aiScene*] and is property of [Assimp::Importer](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html) class. There is function Assimp::Importer::GetOrphanedScene() which could return imported scene and release ownership from Importer, but i don't know how to properly delete this scene afterwards (Docs say that after releasing it would become my headpain).

Comment: Does the function modify the object you pass a pointer to?

Comment: I don't think so. I should try to copy paste source of this function and change prototype from *aiScene to const *aiScene

Answer (score 0):

If the function does not modify the object, then you should correct it to take a const pointer if you can. If you can't modify the function then it's acceptable to use `const_cast` here to make the code compile. However it's up to you to make sure the object won't get changed, otherwise bad things could happen.